# Rewrite Rules to revert URL structure?

Tags: url-rewrite, magento1.9.2.4, redirect-url, 301-redirect

I've got a site which at some point in the past used SEO friendly category pagination for example :

```
category/subcategory/40.html
category/subcategory/4.html
category/subcategory/15.html
category/subcategory/45.html
category/10.html
category/34.html
category/45.html
category/65.html
```

The site has since reverted to the default functional URL's such as :

```
  category/subcategory?p=40
    category/subcategory?p=4
    category/subcategory?p=15
    category/subcategory?p=45
    category?p=10
    category?p=34
    category?p=45
    category?p=65
```

Could anyone help with any possible rewrite rules that wouldn't conflict with any other part of the site,  but would capture and 301 the previously used to the current?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you using magento? which version?

Comment: Sorry should have said, Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: Are you looking for a solution within Magento or a workaround at web server app is welcome as well? In the second case, please specify your web server and its version.

Comment: I assumed it would be a case of some rewrites for the htaccess ragex ,   server is running lightspeed.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+(/[^/]+)?)/(\d+)\.html$ $1?p=$3 [L,R=301]` (if you are sure .htaccess rules are being processed currently)

Comment: That seems to be working for the most part,  i have just realised though there are some URL's  that instead of having category/65.html ,  they have category/65.5.html ,  which i think are old item size URL's .  Is there anyway to capture those in the same rewrite ?   If so if you put it in an answer instead of comment i can reward you the bounty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By leveraging web server capabilities on working with .htaccess rules and having `RewriteRule` module enabled, you could write a rule as the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+(?:/[^/]+)?)/(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?\.html$ $1?p=$2 [L,R=301]
```

Regex breakdown:

- `^` Assert beginning of path
- `/?` Match an optional slash mark
- `(` Start of 1st capturing group

  - `[^/]+` Match anything but a slash mark (at least one character)
  - `(?:/[^/]+)?` Repeat previous match with a leading slash mark (optional)
- `)` End of 1st capturing group
- `/` Match a mandatory slash mark
- `(\d+)` Match one or a sequence of digits (and hold it in 2nd capturing group)
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Match an optional decimal part
- `\.html` Match `.html`
- `$` Assert end of path

Now that it stores two required values in two separate groups we can use them in our replacement string:

```
$1?p=$2
```

`$1` refers to first capturing group value and `$2` to the second one. This rule matches e.g.

```
category/sub-category/65.5.html
```

and redirects to:

```
category/sub-category?p=65
```

Comment: Awesome thats exactly what I was looking for thank you Revo,  and thank you for such an indepth answer.   I've marked your answer as correct and will release the bounty in a few hours when it becomes releasable

Comment: You are welcome.